# How to render sprites for a snake game using SFML and C++

Tags: c++, logic, rendering, sprite, sfml

The game works fine, but its using rectangle shapes and I want to render the snake parts using Sprites. Here is the code (Yeah It's not that clean I just wanted to get this working):

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>  // Graphics module
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>     // Sound module
#include <iostream>           // Basic input/output (for errors)
#include <vector>             // Dynamic arrays (for snake body)
#include <random>             // For random food positions

class Game {
private:
    sf::Vector2u windowSize;        // Size of the game window
    int a, b;                       // Length and width of a block
    sf::RenderWindow window;        // Window object for drawing
    sf::Font font;                  // Text font
    sf::Clock clock;                // For time measurement
    std::vector<sf::Vector2i> body; // Snake body (segments as coordinates)
    sf::Vector2i food;              // Food position
    sf::Vector2i direction;         // Snake direction
    int score;                      // Player's score
    bool gameOver;                  // Game state: finished or not
    int n, m;                       // Number of rows and columns
    float delay, timer;             // Update delay and elapsed time
    sf::Music eat;                  // Sound effect for eating

public:
    Game(unsigned short x, unsigned short y); // Constructor
    void start();                   // Start the game
private:
    void loop();                    // Main game loop
    void events();                  // Process events (keyboard, etc.)
    void update();                  // Update game logic
    void render();                  // Render elements on screen
    void gameOverScreen();          // Show "Game Over" screen
    sf::Vector2i getFoodPosition(); // Generate new food position
};

int WinMain() {
    Game game(800, 600);
    game.start();
}

int main() {
    Game game(800, 600);    // Create object with window size 800x600
    game.start();           // Call the start function
}

Game::Game(uint16_t x, uint16_t y) {
    windowSize = { x, y };  // Save window width and height
    window.create(sf::VideoMode(windowSize.x, windowSize.y, 1), "Snake");
    // Create the window
    a = 50;                 // Set block width
    b = 50;                 // Set block height
    n = windowSize.x / a;   // Calculate number of horizontal blocks
    m = windowSize.y / b;   // Calculate number of vertical blocks
    font.loadFromFile("resources/Fonts/sfpro_bold.OTF"); // Load font for text
    eat.openFromFile("resources/Audio/eating_apple.mp3");
}

void Game::start() {
    body.clear();            // Clear the snake body
    body.push_back({ 5,3 }); // Head
    body.push_back({ 4,3 }); // Body segment
    body.push_back({ 3,3 }); // Tail
    direction = { 0, 0 };    // Direction
    food = { getFoodPosition() }; // Initial food position
    gameOver = false;        // Game not over (false)
    score = 0;               // Start score from 0
    loop();                  // Main loop
}

void Game::loop() {
    timer = 0.f;             // Accumulated time
    delay = 0.125f;          // Game update delay
    while (window.isOpen()) {
        events();            // Handle user inputs (keyboard and mouse)
        timer += clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds(); // Add elapsed time in seconds to the timer
        if (timer > delay) {
            update();        // Update the game (move snake, etc.)
            render();        // Render the screen (blocks, snake, food, text, etc.)
            timer = 0;       // Reset timer
        }
        clock.restart();    // Restart the clock for the next cycle
    }
}

void Game::events() {
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
        if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed) {
            if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape) window.close();
            else if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Up && (direction.y != 1)) direction = { 0, -1 };
            else if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Down && (direction.y != -1)) direction = { 0, 1 };
            else if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Left && (direction.x != 1)) direction = { -1, 0 };
            else if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Right && (direction.x != -1)) direction = { 1, 0 };
            else if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::R) /*if (gameOver)*/ start();
        }
    }
}

void Game::update() {
    if (gameOver || direction == sf::Vector2i{ 0,0 }) return;
    sf::Vector2i newHead = body[0] + direction;
    for (size_t i = 1; i < body.size(); i++) {
        if (newHead == body[i]) {
            gameOver = true;
            return;
        }
    }
    if (newHead.x > n - 1 || newHead.x < 0 || newHead.y > m - 1 || newHead.y < 0) {
        gameOver = true;
        return;
    }
    if (newHead == food) {
        body.insert(body.begin(), newHead);
        food = getFoodPosition();
        score++;
        eat.play();
    }
    else {
        body.insert(body.begin(), newHead);
        body.pop_back();
    }
}

void Game::render() {
    window.clear();
    sf::RectangleShape block(sf::Vector2f(a, b));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            block.setPosition(i * a, j * b);
            int p = (i + j) % 2;
            block.setFillColor(sf::Color(172 - p * 7, 214 - p * 7, 67 - p * 7, 255));
            window.draw(block);
        }
    }

    block.setPosition(food.x * a, food.y * b);
    block.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
    window.draw(block);

    for (int i = 0; i < body.size(); i++) {
        if (i == 0)
            block.setFillColor(sf::Color::Magenta);
        else
            block.setFillColor(sf::Color(0, 71, 181));
        block.setPosition(body[i].x * a, body[i].y * b);
        window.draw(block);
    }

    sf::Text scr("Score: " + std::to_string(score), font, 32);
    scr.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
    scr.setPosition(4, 0);
    window.draw(scr);
    if (gameOver) gameOverScreen();

    window.display();
}

void Game::gameOverScreen() {
    eat.stop();
    sf::RectangleShape screen({ float(windowSize.x), float(windowSize.y) });
    screen.setPosition({ 0,0 });
    screen.setFillColor(sf::Color(0, 0, 0, 100));
    sf::Text gameOverText("      Game over!\nPress R to restart", font, 38);
    gameOverText.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
    gameOverText.setPosition((windowSize.x / 2) - 150, (windowSize.y / 2) - 20);
    window.draw(screen);
    window.draw(gameOverText);
}

sf::Vector2i Game::getFoodPosition() {                  
    std::random_device randomDevice;                     
    std::mt19937 randomNumberGenerator(randomDevice());  

    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distX(0, n - 1);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distY(0, m - 1);
    sf::Vector2i position;                               
    do {
        position.x = distX(randomNumberGenerator);       
        position.y = distY(randomNumberGenerator);       
        if (std::find(body.begin(), body.end(), position) == body.end()) {   
            return position;                             
        }
    } while (true);                                      
}
```

The code above does not have sprites functionality currently, but here is an approach I have tried  (which worked for the rendering the sprites): Created a map of Textures and Sprites, loaded the textures from the files, mapped them to the Sprites, and then I had a map of Sprites ready. This part was not that hard I had flaws in my rendering logic most likely. Code was taken from when I had the sprite logic, Im basically using a string to determine which sprite I should load.

```
sf::Vector2i prev = body[i + 1]; // 
sf::Vector2i next = body[i - 1]; //because i pop the tail and insert new part at the beginning
if (next.x == prev.x) {
    spriteName = "body_vertical"; //vertical sprite |
}
else if (next.y == prev.y) {
    spriteName = "body_horizontal"; // horizontal   --
}
else {
    if (prev.x < next.x) {
        if (prev.y > next.y) 
                spriteName = "body_topright"; // start top curve right downwards 
            else 
                spriteName = "body_bottomleft"; // bottom -> left
        }
        else if (prev.y < next.y) {
            spriteName = "body_topleft"; // top -> left
            
        else 
                spriteName = "body_bottomright"; // bottom -> right
        }
    }
    else{
        if (prev.y > next.y) {
                spriteName = "body_topleft"; // top -> left
            else
                spriteName = "body_bottomright"; // bottom -> right
        }
        else if (prev.y < next.y) {
                spriteName = "body_topright"; // top -> right
            else 
                spriteName = "body_bottomleft"; // bottom -> left
        }
    }
}
```

Link for sprites: [opengameart.org/content/snake-game-assets](https://opengameart.org/content/snake-game-assets). Basically, what I want is some feedback on how to choose the correct sprite to load and for which situation (head and tail would be appreciated too ). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

here's a slightly cleaner code,

```
// choosing is based on the assumption
// that the head is the last element in the body array
// if not, you can simply reverse the conditions
if (prev == /*last in body*/) {
  spriteName == "head_sprite";
} else if (prev == /*first in body*/) {
  spriteName = "tail_sprite";
} else if (next.x == prev.x || next.y == prev.y) {
  spriteName == "body_sprite";
} else {
  spriteName = "curved_sprite";
}
// now rotate and reverse
if (prev.x == next.x) {
  // rotate 90deg
} else if (prev.x > next.x) {
  // reverse horizontally
}

if (prev.y > next.y) {
  // reverse vertically
}
```

it's much more convenient to rotate/reverse the sprite than choosing individual sprites based on each case.

i have selected from the snake_graphics.zip you attached those sprites

> ["head_down", "tail_down", "body_vertical", "body_bottomright"]

and renamed them to

> ["head_sprite", "tail_sprite", "body_sprite", "curved_sprite" ]

respectively.
i possibly might have mistaken in rotating/reversing the sprite
as i don't know for sure whether prev or next is the current ("assumed prev is"), but that's the basic idea